# MySQL SUM of a COUNT with GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, sum

I wish to `SUM` the `COUNT` of a query as follows. This query returns the count properly (1) for each row, but not sure how to add them all up.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), jss_orders_headers.*  FROM jss_orders_headers
LEFT JOIN jss_orders_extrafields
ON jss_orders_headers.orderID = jss_orders_extrafields.orderID
AND jss_orders_extrafields.extraFieldID = 5
GROUP BY jss_orders_headers.orderID
ORDER BY jss_orders_headers.orderID DESC
```

Table Structure is

### jss_order_headers

orderID,
etc

### jss_order_extrafields

exid,
orderID,
extrafieldID,
extrafieldName,
content

This currently returns data as follows:

### COUNT() | orderID  | etc

1   |  99

1   |      104

1   |      106

I need to return the `SUM` of the `COUNT()` column. So in the 3 examples above I would return `3`.

Many thanks

Comment: I see that you posted some details but can you post data from each table and then what you expect as the result from the query?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear but if you only want the `sum()` of all `orders`, then you should be able to use something like this:

```
select sum(TotalByOrder) TotalOrders
from
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) TotalByOrder, jss_orders_headers.*  
  FROM jss_orders_headers
  LEFT JOIN jss_orders_extrafields
    ON jss_orders_headers.orderID = jss_orders_extrafields.orderID
    AND jss_orders_extrafields.extraFieldID = 5
  GROUP BY jss_orders_headers.orderID
) src
```

Comment: Thank you bluefeet. What does the src bit do at the end?

Comment: @Jeepstone `src` is the alias for the subquery.

Comment: I thought so, but interesting that the query doesn't run without it?

Comment: @Jeepstone some databases require an alias on subqueries and derived tables, MySQL is one that does.

Comment: If don't give an alias it throws an error "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias". Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: How this will affect the performance if there are millions of records, because it is selecting all the records from the table. Is there any other solution to this without calling all the records?

Answer (score 14):

Would [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) do what you need?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), jss_orders_headers.*  FROM jss_orders_headers
LEFT JOIN jss_orders_extrafields
ON jss_orders_headers.orderID = jss_orders_extrafields.orderID
AND jss_orders_extrafields.extraFieldID = 5
GROUP BY jss_orders_headers.orderID DESC WITH ROLLUP
```

Why there's no `ORDER BY`?

> When you use ROLLUP, you cannot also use an ORDER BY clause to sort
>   the results. In other words, ROLLUP and ORDER BY are mutually
>   exclusive. **However**, you still have some control over sort order. GROUP
>   BY in MySQL sorts results, and you can use explicit ASC and DESC
>   keywords with columns named in the GROUP BY list to specify sort order
>   for individual columns.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything. I've added sample data.

Comment: I wonder if you might try switching jss_orders_headers.* to be jss_orders_headers.orderID.  Does that help?